# How does one extract a command's exit status into a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, exit-status

I started learning Bash a couple of days ago.

I'm trying to obtain an exit status of `grep` expression into a variable like this:

```
check=grep -ci 'text' file.sh
```

and the output that I got is

```
No command '-ic' found
```

Should I do it with a pipe command?

Comment: For exit status you can examine `$?` right after command is finished.

Comment: and you can examine the PIPESTATUS array if you want the status of one of the commands in a pipeline.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your command,

```
check=grep -ci 'text' file.sh
```

will be interpreted by the shell as "run the command `-ci` with the arguments `text` and `file.sh`, and set the variable `check` to the value `grep` in its environment".

---

The shell stores the exit value of most recently executed command in the variable `?`.  You can assign its value to one of your own variables like this:

```
grep -i 'PATTERN' file
check=$?
```

If you want to act on this value, you may either use your `check` variable:

```
if [ "$check" -eq 0 ]; then
    # do things for success
else
    # do other things for failure
fi
```

or you could skip using a separate variable and having to inspect `$?` all together:

```
if grep -q -i 'pattern' file; then
  # do things (pattern was found)
else
  # do other things (pattern was not found)
fi
```

(note the `-q`, it instructs `grep` to not output anything and to exit as soon as something matches; we aren't really interested in what matches here)

Or, if you just want to "do things" when the pattern is *not* found:

```
if ! grep -q -i 'pattern' file; then
  # do things (pattern was not found)
fi
```

---

Saving `$?` into another variable is only ever needed if you need to use it later, when the value in `$?` has been overwritten, as in

```
mkdir "$dir"
err=$?

if [ "$err" -ne 0 ] && [ ! -d "$dir" ]; then
    printf 'Error creating %s (error code %d)\n' "$dir" "$err" >&2
    exit "$err"
fi
```

In the above code snippet, `$?` will be overwritten by the result of the `[ "$err" -ne 0 ] && [ ! -d "$dir" ]` test.  Saving it here is really only necessary if we need to display it and use it with `exit`.

Answer (score 9):

You've told bash to set the variable `check=grep` in the environment it passes to the command

> `-ci 'text' file.sh`

but `ci` does not exist.

I believe you meant to enclose that command in back-ticks, or in parentheses preceded by a dollar sign, either of which would assign the count of how many lines 'text' was found on (case insensitively) in the file:

```
check=`grep -ci 'text' file.sh`

check=$(grep -ci 'text' file.sh)
```

Now `$check` should be 0 if no matches, or positive if there were any matches.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is unclear but based on the code you’ve submitted, it looks like you want the variable `check` to store the exit status of the `grep` command. The way to do this is to run

```
grep -ci 'text' file.sh
check=$?
```

When running a command from a shell, its exit status is made available through the special shell parameter, `$?`.

This is documented by POSIX (the standard for Unix-like operating systems) in
its [specification for the shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02) and the Bash implementation is documented under [Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters).

Since you’re a new learner, I’d strongly recommend that you start with a good book and/or online tutorial to get the basics. Recommendations of external resources are discouraged on Stack Exchange sites but I’d suggest [Lhunath and GreyCat’s Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Answer (score 2):

Confused why using -c when checking the output? It's used to check how many times something is matched - not if it's successful or not.

```
   -c, --count
          Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching  lines
          for  each  input  file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see
          below), count non-matching lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)
```

but in this example

```
check="$(grep --silent -i 'text' file.sh; echo $?)"
```

It doesn't output anything except a exit code, which is then echoed. This is the output that the variable check uses. I also prefer it because it's a single line.

You can replace --silent with -q. I use it since you're not interested in the grep output, just whether it worked or not.

```
   -q, --quiet, --silent
          Quiet;  do  not  write  anything  to  standard   output.    Exit
          immediately  with  zero status if any match is found, even if an
          error was detected.  Also see the -s  or  --no-messages  option.
          (-q is specified by POSIX.)
```

---

```
$ check=$(echo test | grep -qi test; echo $?) # check variable is now set
$ echo $check
0
$ check=$(echo null | grep -qi test; echo $?)
$ echo $check
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Other answers clarify why your command is not working, and some great suggestions as to how to test its result. I'd like to add one more.

## $(command)$? appends the exit code

You can do this using a combination of command substitution and exit code checking, all in one line. It will append the exit code to the output as a number.

```bsh
check=$( grep -ci 'text' file.sh )$?
```

This is actually `$(some command)` (get the string output of a command) immediately followed by `$?` (get the exit code of the last command). To work, they have to be used together with no space.

Source: https://www.assertnotmagic.com/2018/06/20/bash-brackets-quick-reference/#-dollar-single-parentheses-dollar-q-

If there is any possibility of output, which is the case with most commands, you will have to suppress it using `> /dev/null 2>&1`.

This may not be necessary if you're using a test command such as `test -d <directory>`.

```bsh
check=$( grep -ci 'text' file.sh > /dev/null 2>&1)$?
```

You could use a function to abstract this away:

```bsh
e() {
    $@ > /dev/null 2>&1
}

# Usage:
check=$(e grep -ci 'text' file.sh)$?
```

### Testing the exit code

To use this later, test against zero (success):

```bsh
[ $check -eq 0 ] && echo "passed" || echo "didn't pass"

[ $check -ne 0 ] && echo "didn't pass" || echo "passed"
```

Using an if/then/else construct, testing against zero (success):

```bsh
if [ $check -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "passed"
else
    echo "didn't pass"
fi

if [ $check -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "didn't pass"
else
    echo "passed"
fi
```

#### Testing exit code directly

Using `exit` within a `(`subshell`)` will produce a proper exit code from the number which you can use directly:

```bsh
(exit $check) && echo "check passed" || echo "check didn't pass"

! (exit $check) && echo "check didn't pass" || echo "check passed"
```

Using an if/then/else construct, using exit code directly:

```bsh
if (exit $check); then
    echo "passed"
else
    echo "didn't pass"
fi

if ! (exit $check); then
    echo "didn't pass"
else
    echo "passed"
fi
```

Using `return` instead of `exit` will also work in some shells - zsh included (but not bash).

#### Getting fancy

If you want to simplify even more, use this function:

```bsh
t() { return $1; }
```

and now you can test like this:

```bsh
t $check && echo "passed" || echo "didn't pass"

! t $check && echo "didn't pass" || echo "passed"
```

Comment: **1)** `check=(grep -ci 'text' file.sh)` creates array containing elements "grep", "-ci" "text" "file.sh". `echo $check` will print only first element, to get all you need `echo ${check[*]}`. **2)** `check=$(command)$?` will store output of command and append exit code. try `check=$(echo "a b c")$?; echo $check`

Comment: Ah, you're right! Will edit.

Comment: This answer helps a lot in my case, where I use `set -e` in my bash script. With this setting checking exit status in a new line results in  terminating the script in case of non-zero exit status of a command. `$(command)$?` syntax works as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to assign the output of grep command to a variable is as @monty-harder mentioned:

```
check=`grep -ci 'text' file.sh`
check=$(grep -ci 'text' file.sh)
```

Though to assign the exit status of this command to a variable you have to use the shell parameter `$?` right after executing the command as shown below:

```
grep -ci 'text' file.sh
check=$?
echo $check
```

Answer (score -1):

For my case I ended up doing something like:

```bsh
code=$(grep -ci 'text' file.sh 2>&1 > /dev/null; echo $?)
echo $code
0
```

Works if you are only interested in the return code and you are willing to discard. `stdout` and `stderr`

Comment: Why do you store the output of the commands in `code` if you don't end up using `$code`? This would be equivalent to `grep -ci 'text' file.sh 2>&1` followed by `echo 0` (what you are outputting is actually the exit status of `echo` in the command substitution, which will be zero).  It would also be better to use `grep -q -i` than `grep -c -i` as you're throwing away the output anyway: `grep -q -i 'text' file.sh; echo "$?"` (your code corrected). But this is just re-iterating what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I fixed it. The reason why I did not mention ```-q``` is because not all commands have a silent mode, so for this particular example may not be the best approach, but for other solutions it's a valid one. And my answer provides something different comparing to the other answers so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The `-q` option for `grep` is standard, and always available.

Comment: Yes I just meant that a silent mode is not available for other commands other than ```grep``` since what lead me here was a different command.