# get output and return value of grep in single operation in bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep, exit-status

I am writing a bash script; I execute a certain command and grep.

```
pfiles $1 2> /dev/null | grep name # $1 Process Id
```

The response will be something like:

```
sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.10.50.28  port: 22
peername: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.16.6.150  port: 12295
```

The response can be no lines, 1 line, or 2 lines.
In case grep returns no lines (grep return code 1), I abort the script; if I get 1 line I invoke A() or B() if more than 1 line. grep's return code is 0 when the output is 1-2 lines.

grep has return value (0 or 1) and output.
How can I catch them both ? If I do something like:

```
OUTPUT=$(pfiles $1 2> /dev/null | grep peername)
```

Then variable OUTPUT will have the output (string); I also want the boolean value of grep execution.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294371/how-to-obtain-grep-exit-status-into-a-variable

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question. Do you need the output from `grep` at all? Do you need the return value? Would it be enough to just count the matchs, as per my answer below?

Comment: I need the output and return code. $? Might do the job

Comment: @ilansch I added another answer that should satisfy your requirements.

Comment: "variable OUTPUT will have the output (string); I also want the boolean value of grep execution." Where this two values should be stored (boolean value and `grep` output)? In the OUTPUT variable both, each on its own line? Just interesting, what you wanted.

Comment: Yes. In 2 variables. Cant i modify a local variable during the execution?

Answer (score 20):

You can use

```
output=$(grep -c 'name' inputfile)
```

The variable `output` will then contain the number `0`, `1`, or `2`. Then you can use an `if` statement to execute different things.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I’m wondering how this answer ever got any up votes when it does not do what the question asks for — capture the output of `grep` in a variable.

Comment: @Scott, can you clarify what doesn't work?

Comment: The question is a bit muddled, but the OP seems to want the `OUTPUT` variable to contain `sockname: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.10.50.28  port: 22` *`(newline)`* `peername: AF_INET6 ::ffff:10.16.6.150  port: 12295`. As your answer says, it only sets the `output` variable to `2`.

Answer (score 5):

This is fairly simple:

```
OUTPUT=$(pfiles "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep peername)
grep_return_code=$?
```

If a `$(…)` command substitution is assigned to a variable,
`$?` will get the return code from the last command in the `$(…)`. 
And, of course, you don’t need to refer to `$?` explicitly;
you can do things like

```
if OUTPUT=$(pfiles "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep peername)
then
    # the rest of the script
                ︙
fi
```

or

```
if ! OUTPUT=$(pfiles "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep peername)
then
    exit
fi
# the rest of the script
            ︙
```

This approach is useful in situations where the *output* of the command
and its *return code* (a.k.a. exit status) are uncorrelated. 
But, for `grep`, they are highly correlated:
If it produced output, it succeeded. 
If it didn’t produce output, it failed. 
So why not just test the *output* ?

```
OUTPUT=$(pfiles "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep peername)
if [ "$OUTPUT" ]
then
    # the rest of the script
                ︙
fi
```

or

```
OUTPUT=$(pfiles "$1" 2> /dev/null | grep peername)
if [-z "$OUTPUT" ]
then
    exit
fi
# the rest of the script
            ︙
```

P.S. You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$1"`)
unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the result of `grep`, you can not use the `-c` flag as outlined in the other answer. What you can do, though, is running twice, once with `-c` flag to get the number of matches and one without `-c` flag, to see the matches. However, this can be very inefficient, depending on the size of your input file.

You can do something like this:

Content of **input**:

```
The first line is foo
I have a drink at the bar
The third line is foo again
```

Content of **script**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

countMatches(){
    echo Searching for "${1}"
    result=$(grep "${1}" input)
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo No match found
        echo
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ $(echo "${result}" | wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
        echo 1 match found:
        echo "${result}"
        echo
    else
        echo 2 matches found:
        echo "${result}"
        echo
    fi
}

countMatches foo
countMatches bar
countMatches baz
```

And here's the output when you invoke the **script**:

```
Searching for foo
2 matches found:
The first line is foo
The third line is foo again

Searching for bar
1 match found:
I have a drink at the bar

Searching for baz
No match found
```

Comment: (1) You don’t need any of those curly braces in parameter expansions (`${1}` and `${result}`) — quotes alone are enough …  (2) … and you *should* use quotes for `"$?"`.  (3) `grep`, like a few other programs, can exit with a status of 2 for system-level errors (like failure to open or read a file).  If you want to test for failure of a program, you should test for ```"$?" -ne 0```.

Comment: @Scott I fixed point (2) and (3). As for (1), the curly braces are not needed but don't hurt either, it's a matter of style. One could even argue that the quotes around `${1}` or `$?` are not needed either since it's always one word. Thanks for proofreading and feel free to directly edit my posts!

Comment: (4) It’s not valid to say that `$1` doesn’t need to be quoted “since it's always one word” just because ***you*** plan to use arguments that don’t contain spaces or glob characters.  Somebody else might want to call `countMatches` with an argument like `'Local Address'`. (5) As Stéphane Chazelas pointed out in [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](/q/171346/23408#171347), you should write scripts that work correctly even if `IFS` is set to something weird, and even `$#`, `$!` and ```$?``` can suffer from word splitting if they aren’t quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, I feel, it doing what you want.

1. I put `grep` output to the `OUTPUT` variable
2. I think, you don't need `grep` exit status as boolean value. It is 0 or 1, and it doesn't suit to your task. You need amount of lines - 0, 1, 2, etc. Therefore, count lines in the OUTPUT variable and put this number to the second variable - `line_count`. We will have two variables in the result. First with grep output, second with amount of lines.
3. Then, check `line_count` in the `case` statement and do needed action.

**Usage:** `./switching_by_grep_result.sh your_file.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

# your code
OUTPUT=$(pfiles $1 2> /dev/null | grep name) # $1 Process Id

# count lines in the OUTPUT variable by using 'grep -c'
line_count=$(echo -n "$OUTPUT" | grep -c '^')

# checks lines count in here and invokes needed script or exit.
# if 0 lines - exit
# if 1 lines - invoke A
# if any other number of lines - invoke B
case $line_count in  
    0) echo 'exit'
    ;;  
    1) echo 'A() script invoking here'
    ;;  
    *) echo 'B() script invoking here'
    ;;  
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this whilst trying to figure out how to use grep as a test for some piped output, whilst still showing that output regardless. Note that I'm not grepping a file, but stdin.

My particular example is as follows:

```
./manage.py --dry-run makemigrations | grep "No changes detected"
```

The return code is 0 (success) when `No changes detected`. The return code is 1 (fail) when there are changes - but grep doesn't match and so the required changes are not printed!

My solution was as follows

```
./manage.py --dry-run makemigrations | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q "No changes detected"
```

This will always print the output, but will still return the correct error code.